# How to remove lines that does not end with numbers?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file Mytext.txt that looks like this,

```
0 1 A
1 2 T
2 3 A
3 4 B
4 5 A
5 6  
6 7 A
7 8 D
8 9 C
9 10  
10 11 M
11 12 Z
12 13 H
```

What is the easiest way in python with which I can remove the lines that do not end with a letter? So the above becomes

```
0 1 A
1 2 T
2 3 A
3 4 B
4 5 A
6 7 A
7 8 D
8 9 C
10 11 M
11 12 Z
12 13 H
```

Comment: You are removing the lines that *do* end in numbers. Did you mean "do not end with *letters*"?

Comment: Could you show us the code that you already tried?

Comment: you can do `line.split(' ')[-1].isnumeric()` to check if the last element is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('Mytext.txt', 'r') as fin:
    with open('Newtext.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.rstrip()[-1].isalpha()
                fout.write(line)
```